# How to auto-generate resource based URI in middleware for front end to consume?

Tags: c#, frontend, uri, middleware

I'm looking a reusable way to auto-generate URI strings in the middleware and pass them to back to front end for it to use them.

I want it able the generate uri for any resources that are associated with it. Timesheet has a many to one relationship with payrolls.

I'm using c# with Entity models, passing JSON to a React front-end.

I want the middleware to generate the URIs that front end will use so that if changes are made to uri structures in the middleware, the front end doesn't need to change how it requests data.

Right now I'm just creating the Uris the resource's class object is populated.

I've looked into something called a Vanity method, but I don't think that is what I'm be looking for to accomplish.

What I'm currently using.

```
public int ID
{
   get { return id; }
   set
   {
      id = value;
      updateApis();
   }
}
public string CheckURI { get; set; }
public string TimeSheetURI { get; set; }
public string PayrollURI { get; set; }

private void updateApis()
        {
            CheckURI = "/api/checks?filter=payroll&id=" + ID;
            TimeSheetURI = "/api/timesheets?id=" + ID;
            PayrollURI = "/api/payroll/" + ID;

        }
```

So when the front end request for a list payrolls like so(this finding payrolls associated with a client id):

```
my.site.com/api/payrolls?id=1&pagesize=10&pagenumber=1
```

It returns a JSON with a list of payroll objects, each with a uri for details on that payroll and any resources front end may need. And a uri for more payrolls based on pagination.

```
{
  "1":{
        "payrollID":"1",
        "clientID":"1",
        "payrollURI":"/api/payrolls/1",
        "checkURI": "/api/checks?id=1",
        "timesheetURI": "/api/timesheets?id=1"
   },
  "2": {
        "payrollID":"2",
        "clientID":"1",
        "payrollURI":"/api/payrolls/2",
        "checkURI": "/api/checks?id=2",
        "timesheetURI": "/api/timesheets?id=2"
   },
  ...,
  "10": {
        "payrollID":"10",
        "clientID":"1",
        "payrollURI":"/api/payrolls/10",
        "checkURI": "/api/checks?id=10",
        "timesheetURI": "/api/timesheets?id=10"
   },
  "additionalRows":"/api/payrolls?id=1&pagesize=10&pagenumber=2"

}
```

So I want it to auto-generate payrollURI, checkURI, timesheetURI, with each payrollID.
And additionalRows with the original URI information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .Select() method and anonymous objects to transform each timesheet into the formatted object you want.

```
context.Timesheets.Select(t => new { 
    CheckURI = "/api/checks?filter=payroll&id=" + t.ID,
    TimeSheetURI = "/api/timesheets?id=" + t.ID,
    PayrollURI = "/api/payroll/" + t.ID
  });
```